# Why this Trigger is not executing?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am using a `trigger` to fire after the insert in the admitted_student`using mysql.
This is my`trigger` code:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER Record_after_insert
AFTER INSERT
   ON admitted_student FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

   DECLARE who varchar(50);
   DECLARE IDD int (15);
   SELECT admitted_student_id FROM admitted_student ORDER BY admitted_student_id DESC into IDD;
   SELECT USER() INTO who;
   INSERT INTO student_audit
   ( id,
     attime,
     who)
   VALUES
   ( IDD,
     SYSDATE(),
     who);
END; 
DELIMITER ;
```

This is my table on which I am using trigger:

[image]

And this the table for my Trigger:

[image]

When I Execute the trigger code then it gives me the following Error:

[image]

Comment: You change the delimiter to `//` but never use it.

Comment: What are you trying to do with that first select stmt?

Comment: iirc the proper more realistic format would be `SELECT admitted_student_id INTO IDD FROM admitted_student ORDER BY admitted_student_id DESC LIMIT 1;` to limit the scope to zero or one value else that thing explodes the way you have it

Comment: To encourage people to answer your questions, it might help if you marked your prior ones Answered with the green check mark. Like this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39455707/how-to-add-form-with-in-another-form-using-ajax-but-remember-first-form-is-also#comment66233198_39455916 . You told him he saved your life. Mark those answered. That's how we roll here.

Comment: Your 4 column table has 4 non null columns. You appear to be supplying only 3 (`action` is forsaken). Your first select stmt is not needed. You would use the `NEW.admitted_student_id` in lieu of it. The manual shows what `NEW` means for triggers :p

Comment: @Drew sorry Now I marked the answer

Comment: @Drew i am selecting last record id from the table to insert in the audit table.

Comment: When you say Last that is interpretted as `NEW` for triggers. Your `NEW`. You are inserting a new row. Your trigger fires. In the meantime other people could be putting stuff in.

Comment: @Drew now i Ues the NEW near the the id but it is giving error in the syntax of `DELIMITER`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124189/discussion-between-bilal-saqib-and-drew).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For non-PHPMyAdmin try:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS Record_after_insert;
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER Record_after_insert
AFTER INSERT
   ON admitted_student FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
   INSERT INTO student_audit (action,id,attime,who)
   SELECT 'something',NEW.admitted_student_id,now(),CURRENT_USER();
END; //
DELIMITER ;
```

for PHPMyAdmin try:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS Record_after_insert;
CREATE TRIGGER Record_after_insert
AFTER INSERT
   ON admitted_student FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
   INSERT INTO student_audit (action,id,attime,who)
   SELECT 'something',NEW.admitted_student_id,now(),CURRENT_USER();
END;
```

PHPMyAdmin doesn't user a `DELIMITER`. `CURRENT_USER()` is the user you resolved to on login.

`who VARCHAR(10)` ought to be like `VARCHAR(100)`.

`attime` should be a `DATETIME` not what it is.